# Transform regular grammar in linear grammar

Tags: terminology, formal-grammars

My problem is how can I transform a *regular* grammar into a *linear* grammar?

I know that a linear grammar has the form

$\begin{align} A &\to w_1Bw_2 \\ 
               A &\to w \end{align}$

where $A,B \in N$ and $w,w_1,w_2 \in \Sigma^*$.

Comment: This question is easily solved by reading the corresponding Wikipedia article. Please make it a habit to check obvious references before you post questions. (Maybe it should have been $\Sigma^*$?)

Comment: Part of [Exercise 6.1.b](http://www.tks.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/teaching/ss12/th-inf-2#exercises), due May 31st.

Answer (score 1):

A (right) regular grammar is one in which all production rules are of one of the following:

$$B \rightarrow a$$
$$B \rightarrow aC$$
$$B \rightarrow \lambda$$

Where $B$ is a non-terminal, $a$ is a terminal and $\lambda$ is the empty word. A regular grammar is a grammar which is either right-regular xor left-regular. As you have said in a linear grammar one does not require the nonterminals to appear on the far side of the right of the production rules. Therefore, every regular grammar is already a linear grammar.

Comment: ie. Pick $w_2=\lambda$

Comment: but how can i modify a regular grammar into a linear grammar??

Comment: a regular grammar IS a linear grammar. You don't need to do any transforming.

Answer (score 1):

*regular* in what sense?

- If you mean *regular* in the sense of a regular language then the question is trivial since [regular grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) is [already](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar#Relationship_with_regular_grammars) a linear grammar.
- If you mean *regular* in the sense of a *customary* or *usual* i.e.

  > How to transform an arbitrary context-free grammar into a linear grammar?

  then this is not possible since [there are examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar#Expressive_power) of context free grammars that generate languages that are not recognizable by a linear context free grammar. (e.g. the [Dyck language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language))

(Both answers can easily be found in the corresponding wikipedia article.)

Comment: the question is to transform a regular grammar into a linear grammar with few variables

Comment: @user1594: what do you mean by "with few variables"? (Also: why any answer here is not enough for you?)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your definition is equivalent to the more informal one from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar):

> [A] grammar is linear if it is context-free and all of its productions' right hand sides have at most one nonterminal.

So every regular grammar is linear *by definition*. That is why regular grammars are also called right- or left-linear (depending on which one you choose).

Formally, choose $w_1=\varepsilon$ (or $w_2=\varepsilon$) *for all rules* to obtain a left-regular (or right-regular) grammar.

Comment: I think that his definition is equivalent, as he allows $w_1$ and $w_2$ to be empty.

Comment: @SamJones: Right. The $^*$ was missing earlier. Editing to adapt.

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't notice that it had started without a star.